# Stack Images with a divider in between with Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am wanting to combine two images with Python. I have gotten this part down, but I am wanting to have like a 20 pixel wide divider in between them and I am not sure how to go about that.
Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
from PIL import Image

list_im = ['image002.jpg', 'image002aA_nowrap_5.jpg']
imgs    = [ PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]


min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]

imgs_comb = np.vstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )
imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.save( '002_vertical.jpg' )
```

For example, it will take the two pictures I have attached and stack it like the third one.
This is my first time posting so if the pictures do not post correctly I apologize in advance.

I would also like to be able to run this code and have it loop through my folder because I want to do this to a few hundred pairs of images, I am also not sure how to approach that loop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6zY7.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kc5y.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNF2r.jpg

Comment: Setting up some additional divider image isn't that difficult, e.g. `divider = Image.new('RGB', (min_shape[0], 20), (0, 0, 0))` for a black, 20 px high divider of proper width. Place that image between your actual two images in `imgs`, and you're done. To generalize that, and also to add that looping part, it'd be necessary to know your folder structure. How do you select each two (or even more?) images to be stacked? Do you have sub-folders? Do you have certains names, which could be used to get all images belonging to one stack?

Comment: Oh I didn't even think about just making a new image and add it in there. Thanks that works! At the moment I have all the images in one directory along with my code and just run the code using the image file. I could take my images and put all of the ones I want on top in one folder and the ones I want in another folder, then just call the folders using the complete path name. Should I list the image names in a text file and call them in a for loop that just adds 1 to the image name (I have them named a way where I think that may work) until it has ran through them all?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me!